# Too many Tunnel Adapter Interfaces

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv6, ipconfig

If I open a command prompt on my machine and type `ipconfig /all`, I see lots of

```
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media state . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Sufficx . . . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #5
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . : Yes
```

In fact, they're so many that my "real" adapters are pushed out of the stack, and can't be seen anymore. Is there any flag I can use on `ipconfig` to hide all virtual interfaces? Or is there some other way around this problem?

Since they always say "Media disconnected" I suppose disabling could be an option, but if possible I'd rather not turn any functionality off. I just want to control what output I get from `ipconfig`.

Also, I know these are related to IPv6 stuff. However, most of what I find on google merely states what these are, and that they're harmless - nothing about hiding/removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way of removing them from the list, but there are two workarounds.  The first and easiest is to not use /all if you don't need it.  If you absolutely need the extra information provided by /all, then the other option is to increases the number of buffered lines.  This can be done by selecting the Layout tab in the properties for cmd.  Simply set the vertical buffer to be larger (300-500 should suffice).

Comment: I certainly would have liked to remove inactive adapters (I just don't see the reason for having them lying around...) but increasing the buffer size to 500 rows did solve my immediate problem: not being able to see the real adapters. Thanks!

Comment: Another option in addition to MBraedley's methods is to use the "ipconfig /all |more" command. It then pauses with each screen, giving you a chance to see what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool at the bottom of [this page](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f137/solved-too-many-tunnel-adapters-439264.html) that is supposed to do it.

The real fix is to disable ipv6. If you open Device Manager and have it show hidden devices, it shows all the tunnel adapters it has installed (the computer I'm fixing right now had over 500).

Comment: Disabling IPv6 does not fix anything, but it does break the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 functionality is enabled by default since windows 7 and most of the 'no media' tunnel adapters are related to 'IPv6 <> IPv4' communication.

Those adapters CAN be disabled, not removed, type by type - so lowering the total amount and still keeping the functionality.

For example two similar systems are `isatap` and `teredo`. Their removal commands are respectively:

```
netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 set teredo disabled
```

Or you can disable IPv6 entirely as well.